# Cancel imageLoader tasks on searching

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-adapter, android-search

My project has a search view with custom adapter,
adapter ViewHolder contain ImageView

I use 2 tasks: 1- search task 2- image load task

so when I start search task, on Post Execute I set data adapter and notif it 
then image loader is execute as much as the number of results!

When I rerun the search task,I Should wait until the tasks of the image loader are finished

Finally how can I cancel ImageLoader tasks before rerun SearchTask??

adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activityReference.get().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row1, parent, false);
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
        viewHolder.artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_artist);
        viewHolder.cover = (FadeInNetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cover);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    viewHolder.title.setText(songs[position].getArtist());
    viewHolder.artist.setText(songs[position].getTitle());


    new ImageLoader().execute(songs[position], this, this, viewHolder, Online.isConnectedWifi(context));

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused.  When you're going to run the search task, do you want it to wait for image loaders or cancel the image loaders?

Comment: @Dziugas I want to cancel Image Loaders because run search task again could change results completely !!

Comment: Ah ok because afterwards you said "When I rerun the search task,I Should wait until the tasks of the image loader are finished".

Comment: @Dziugas AsyncTasks are executed in turns, I meant search task will run when imageloader tasks finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to cancel all the `ImageLoader`s in one swoop, you are going to have to keep reference to them in your adapter and, in your adapter, declare a public method that shall cancel them all:

```
public class MhadisAdapter extends SomeKindOfAdapter {
    private List<ImageLoader> imageLoaderTasks = new ArrayList<>();

    public void cancelImageLoaders() {
        for(ImageLoader task: imageLoaderTasks) {
            task.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        ...
        ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader();
        imageLoaderTasks.add(imageLoader);
        imageLoader.execute(songs[position], this, this, viewHolder, Online.isConnectedWifi(context));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Now you can cancel all the image loaders before searching by calling `cancelImageLoaders()`

Comment: nooooo! That's easy way. It's work perfectly thanks ;)

Comment: No problem. Just make sure to override onCanceled() in your ImageLoader, where you should clean up (close connection etc.)